# Weird Gradle output when building Android projects

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

When I'm building my Android projects by saying `gradlew build` from a `cmd.exe` prompt I always get lots of these one character line outputs from Gradle:

[image: Screenshot]

It builds and works just fine but while building Gradle's output constantly switches between normal lines (in the upper half of the screenshot) and one character lines (in the lower half of the screenshot) which looks quite awkward and makes it difficult to realize what's going on there.

Tested with Gradle 3.5 and the latest Android Studio. I can reproduce this on both Windows 7 and 10 all the time. Anyone know what's wrong there?

Comment: Which version of Android Studio, Android gradle plugin and java?

Comment: Android Studio 2.3.1, Gradle plugin 162.2228.14 and JDK 1.8.0.121.

Comment: cool. Gradle version? type `.\gradlew --version`. Try Gradle 3.5. Also, try running the command in Windows Powershell